# React hooks: get state of useState inside a listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this inside my component:

```
const [ pendingMessages, setPendingMessages ] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(function() {
    ref.current.addEventListener('send-message', onSendMessage);
    return function() {
      ref.current.removeEventListener('send-message', onSendMessage);
    };
  }, []);

function onSendMessage(event) {
  const newMessage = event.message;
  console.log('Here not up to date :(', pendingMessages);
  setPendingMessages([ ...pendingMessages, newMessage ]);
}
```

The problem is that `pendingMessages` is not up to date inside the listener because it's not inside the render. It's already attached. Any ideas how can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is because of a close that is formed when the effect is run. Since you set the `useEffect` to run only on initial mount, it gets the value of `pendingMessages` from the closure that is formed when it is declared and hence even if the the `pendingMessages` updates, `pendingMessages` inside `onSendMessage` will refer to the same value that was present initially.

Since you do not want to access the value in `onSendMessage` and just update the state based on previous value, you could simply use the callback pattern of setter

```
const [ pendingMessages, setPendingMessages ] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(function() {
    ref.current.addEventListener('send-message', onSendMessage);
    return function() {
      ref.current.removeEventListener('send-message', onSendMessage);
    };
  }, []);

function onSendMessage(event) {
  const newMessage = event.message;
  setPendingMessages(prevState =>([ ...prevState, newMessage ]));
}
```