# Inside callback function - always shows initial state

Tags: reactjs, callback, closures, react-hooks, sortablejs

I have a stateful functional react component where I also use sortablejs.

```
const myComponent = () => {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState([...some initial array data...]);
  const testMe = () => console.log(myData)
  useEffect(() => {
   const sortableContainer = document.querySelector(".slick-track");
   Sortable.create(sortableContainer, {
        onEnd: () => testMe() //onEnd is a callback from sortablejs api, that fires after we drag an item
   }, []);
```

And so no matter how myData changes during component life, inside this callback it always shows initial data. So is it possible to get the current `myData` value inside this callback?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54528980/2810565

I just should use prevState like this:

```
const testMe = () => {
     setMyData(currentData => {
             console.log('Here is my current data', currentData); 
             return ([...prevState, //here add changes to state]);
      })
}
```