# TypeError: comments.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm studying react and trying to learn, but I came across this error when I click the send button::

TypeError: comments.map is not a function

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [comments, setComments] = useState(['Comment1', 'Comment 2', 'Etc'])

  const sendComment = () => {
    setComments({
      [comments]: [...comments, 'Comentário']
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { /* New comment */ }
      <div>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <button onClick={sendComment}>Enviar</button>
      </div>
      { /* Comments */ }
      <div>
        { /* Comment */ }
        {comments.map( (comment) => {
          return <div>Comment: {comment} </div>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code is the one above, the intention is as soon as I click on the send button it will generate a new comment with the name "Comment"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  Thanks for posting this, but all posts to stack overflow are requested to be in English.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/) for details.  Perhaps you want [pt.so]?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because all posts to stack overflow are requested to be in English.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/) for details.  Perhaps you want [pt.so]?

Comment: It's usually pointless to translate questions because the asker will not understand it or the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `sendComment` sets the `comments` variable as an object. But it should be an array to access `map` method on it. You can set the comments to an array when you call `setComments` inside the function `sendComment`.

Example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-williamson-qghsi?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState(["Comment1", "Comment 2", "Etc"]);

  const sendComment = () => {
    setComments([...comments, "Comentário"]);
  };

  console.log(comments);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* New comment */}
      <div>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" />
        <button onClick={sendComment}>Enviar</button>
      </div>
      {/* Comments */}
      <div>
        {/* Comment */}
        {comments.map(comment => {
          return <div>Comentário: {comment} </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: And if I wanted to make it an object, how would I do it?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the object structure? Like `{ comments: ["Comment1", "Comment 2", "Etc", "Comment3"] }` or the some structure of the object you want to set?

Comment: When using classes I could define:

state = {
comments: [
"Comment 1",
"Comment 2",
]
}

how do I get to or closer to this using function

Comment: Here is an example. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-tdd-ffwyd?file=/src/App.js). Let me know if that's the solution you wanted or if you need another implementation.

Comment: I was unable to access the link. Could you send me again?

Comment: Here, [https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-tdd-ffwyd?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-tdd-ffwyd?file=/src/App.js). The link is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You originally defined the comments as array but when you click on send, you are setting the comments to be an object, check this quick fix:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState(["Comment1", "Comment 2", "Etc"]);

  const sendComment = () => {
    setComments((comments) => [...comments, "Comentário"]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* New comment */}
      <div>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <button onClick={sendComment}>Enviar</button>
      </div>
      {/* Comments */}
      <div>
        {/* Comment */}
        {comments.map((comment) => {
          return <div>Comentário: {comment} </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `comments` as an array but you're setting the state as an Object.

The correct way is:

```
 const sendComment = () => {
     setComments([...comments, 'Comentário'])
  }
```

Comment: This would not work as expected, you have to pass a function to setComments to get the old comments state.

Comment: It works perfectly fine check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-ives-214hk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have checked your demo and it works perfectly but this is just a basic case. When you do implement useEffect to get comments from API or do other state manipulation or even the component get more complex this approach will cause problems. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528796/react-hooks-get-state-of-usestate-inside-a-listener

Comment: Please write your answers in English on Stack Overflow. I've tried to translate it as close as possible, but I don't speak Portuguese, so please review my edit.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Your translation is correct. Thanks !